# How can I pass a parameter to Sql.execReaderF in FsSql?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am trying out the samples for FsSql and I seem to be stuck on how to properly use the Sql.execReaderF function. The example code uses an int parameter but I have a string. The following code blocks show my attempts. Does FsSql only support int for this function maybe?

Setup code:

```
module FsSqlTests

open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.SqlClient
open NUnit.Framework
open Swensen.Unquote

let openConn() =
        let conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MYSERVER;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Integrated Security=True")
        conn.Open()
        conn :> IDbConnection

let connMgr = Sql.withNewConnection openConn 

let P = Sql.Parameter.make

let execReader sql = Sql.execReader connMgr sql 

let execReaderf sql = Sql.execReaderF connMgr sql
```

Using Sql.execReader (Test case passes using this one)

```
let selectSummaryByeFolderName eFolderName = 
    execReader "select summary from ework.V_DQ_Iccm_Activity_By_Team WHERE efoldername = @eFolderName"
        [P("@eFolderName", eFolderName)]
```

Using Sql.execReaderF (Test case fails using this one)

```
let selectSummaryByeFolderName = 
    execReaderf "select summary from ework.V_DQ_Iccm_Activity_By_Team WHERE efoldername = '%s'"
```

Calling code in the test case:

```
[<TestCase>]
let ``Gets CM summary given eFolderName``() =
    let c = selectSummaryByeFolderName "CM008671"

    let r = c
            |> Seq.ofDataReader
            |> Seq.map(fun dr ->
                let s = 
                    match dr?summary with
                    | None -> "No Summary"
                    | Some x -> x
                s)
            |> Seq.length

    test <@ r > 0 @>
```

How can I modify my call to execReaderF to make it pass the parameter and run correctly?

**UPDATE**:
I tried it out with an integer parameter and it works fine. It seems the function may only support integers.

```
let selectSummaryByCallPriority = 
    execReaderf "select top 10 summary from ework.V_DQ_Iccm_Activity_By_Team WHERE callpriority = %d"
```

I had a look at the implementation to try and verify this but it's over my head. Anyway the Sql.execReader function works fine for other datatypes so I can just switch to that function for my string parameters.

Comment: I'm not familiar with FsSql, but in the examples using `execReaderF`, there is always `conn` as the first parameter and the SQL command as the second one. So maybe you need to pass around the connection object?

Comment: Maybe so. It appeared to me that the connection was being supplied by partial application with the last line in the setup code: let execReaderf sql = Sql.execReaderF connMgr sql

Comment: Hmm, yes, that should be the case! In that case, I'm not sure what's going on here...

Comment: It definitely should be called without the quotes around `%s`.  The %'s are placeholders for parameters, not for the actual values.  You can see here in `stripFormatting` https://github.com/mausch/FsSql/blob/master/FsSql/FsSql.fs that it replaces any `%.` with `@pN`, so your resulting sql is ending up `'@p0'`.  Whether that's the only problem, I don't know.